# \! math symbol in R markdown to beamer with xelatex and lualatex failing

Tags: beamer, math-mode, xetex, luatex, rmarkdown

The following minimal example works correctly within RStudio to generate a pdf beamer slide

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    latex_engine: "pdflatex"
---

##

\[
Z \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp X
\]
```

Unfortunately it generates an error when using lualatex or xelatex engines (as for example below)

```
---
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    latex_engine: "lualatex"
---

##

\[
Z \not\!\perp\!\!\!\perp X
\]
```

The generated error is

! Missing { inserted.

\mskip
l.100 \end{frame}

Any insights about what the problem might be and how to fix it?

Comment: well if you -- as the answer below suggests -- use unicode-math with lualatex, then you really shouldn't use `\not\!\perp`. `\not` expects  a symbol as argument, see 5.5.10 Negations and the \not command in the unicode-math documentation.

Comment: How would you achieve the same result then?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. It is a `tex` MWE that reproduces the problem created by adding a negative thinskip `\!` when compiling with `lualatex`. `\,` and `\;` also generate `Missing { inserted. Z \not\!` and its variants, but `\>` does not generate an error.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
%%% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifLuaTeX
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\fi
\begin{document}
% uncomment lines to generate "Missing { inserted. Z \not\!"
    \[
%   Z \not\!\perp X % No
%   Z \not\,\perp X % No
%   Z \not\;\perp X % No
    Z \not\>\perp X % Yes
    Z \! X          % Yes
    \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why has this gotten a downvote? Ross' too long for comment provides a much more suitable LaTeX MWE than having to go through R markdown